# How to let CREATE TABLE...AS SELECT in HIVE do not populate data?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

When I run CTAS in HIVE, the data is also populated simultaneously. But I just want to create the table, but not populate the data. How and what I should do? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that by using the **LIKE** keyword.

```
create table new_table_name LIKE old_table_name
```

This will create the table structure without the data.

Comment: I will create view first on the complex select, and then issue "create table like view_name"

Answer (score 0):

Use `create EXTERNAL table` instead of `create table`. Observe **External** keyword.

Comment: it seems that it does not work.....hive> create EXTERNAL table p as select * from big_test_table;
create EXTERNAL table p as select * from big_test_table;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10070]: CREATE-TABLE-AS-SELECT cannot create external table

Comment: huh!! It looks external works with external sources, but not hive tables. Just Curious, why do you want to create a hive table from an existing hive table? I mean you can use existing HIVE  table itself, without creating new table

Comment: In fact, the newly created table is from very complex query. And it is not from a simple single table. The query may contain GROUP BY or JOIN.

Comment: ok.. Then wouldn't it be better if you have data populated? I mean next time you query, it will be faster, as it needn't do group by dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Use where condition in select statement and give a value of **where** which fetches no records from hive.

**Example** `table name demo1`

```
id    name      country  
1     abc        India  
2     xyz        Germany  
3     pqr        France

In CREATE TABLE…AS SELECT in HIVE
Create table demo2...As SELECT id, name, country from demo1 where id=0;
```

So, in above where condition of id is given as 0 and from above data the select statement will fetch no record, similarly choose a value in **where** condition which returns no records. Hence no data will be inserted in newly created table.

Comment: It is not the right way. That is a hack and might not work if where condition becomes true in future! To addon, if where clause is never true then that hive table will yield 0 results always and an empty table might not be useful :|

Comment: the select statement may be very complex, i am not sure which column can be used for this purpose.

Comment: As we know, the select is executed by MapReduce job, can we bypass the mapred job ? After this, the table can be still created.

Answer (score 0):

@Sunil's answer helped me as well, I am just posting an addition that was necessary in my case.
The source table was in Avro format but the new one I wanted in ORC, hence,

```
CREATE TABLE dataaggregate_orc_empty LIKE dataaggregate_avro_compressed ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' TBLPROPERTIES ('orc.compress'='ZLIB');
```

The above step can be split in two steps, if required :

```
CREATE TABLE dataaggregate_orc_empty LIKE dataaggregate_avro_compressed;

alter table dataaggregate_orc_empty set fileformat ORC;
```

I would be glad if someone provides inputs for the data format changes that occur in this process and related problems, if any.